# Javascript Remainder is incorrect based on Division

Tags: javascript, modulus

I have a very strange issue using the Javascript remainder (or Modulus) operator.

I have a requirement to get the entire width of a board (excluding margins) and then make sure the `setWidth` value fits directly into the area left.

This means that in the example below the remainder when `area` is divided by `setWidth` the result should be `0`.

Javascript Code :

```
var totalWidth = parseFloat('519');
var setWidth = parseFloat('101.6');
var leftMargin = parseFloat('11');
var rightMargin = parseFloat('0');

var area = (totalWidth - leftMargin) - rightMargin;    
console.log('area : ' + area);
//Incorrect Value given...
var modVal = area % setWidth;
console.log('modVal : ' + modVal);
//Correct value of 5...
var divisionVal = area / setWidth;
console.log('divisionVal : ' + divisionVal);
```

The reason I am parsing the values from strings is because they are actually retrieved from textboxes on the page.

In my [Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bS6yU/6/) I have two different examples, one works as I expect, but the other does not. The only difference is the numbers.

In my example above the values should be as follows :

```
area = (519 - 11) - 0; //Should be 508 (and is)
modVal = 508 % 101.6; //Should be 0 (But isn't for some unknown reason)
divisionVal = 508 / 101.6; //Should be 5 (and is)
```

If anyone can explain to me why one of my examples works and the other doesn't then I'd be happy to hear it. But at the moment I just cannot understand why this doesn't work...

Any ideas?

Comment: 519 / 101.6 is not exactly 5.

Comment: 519 % 101.6 = 11 and because 101.6 * 5 = 508 not 519.

Comment: @Pointy My apologies I mistyped 519 when it was meant to be 508. 508 / 101.6 **is** exactly 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`modVal` gives `2.842170943040401e-14` here, which is `0.00000000000002842170943040401` which is about as close to `0` as you're gonna get with floating point.

Floating point arithmetic can be strange or hard to deal with. Make sure you're well informed.

Comment: Any suggestions on a way to handle this? I can't get around using decimal values.

Comment: How do you want it handled? If you know the precision you can multiply by `10*n` and do integer arithmetic. You can also change comparison with zero to `-e < result < e` where `e` is a very small number.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll probably use the integer arithmetic option, I don't think our precision requirement will be too difficult with this.

Answer (score 0):

Floating-point `%` in JavaScript is pretty bizarre:

> In the remaining cases, where neither an infinity, nor a zero, nor NaN is involved, the floating-point remainder r from a dividend n and a divisor d is defined by the mathematical relation r = n − (d × q) where q is an integer that is negative only if n/d is negative and positive only if n/d is positive, and whose magnitude is as large as possible without exceeding the magnitude of the true mathematical quotient of n and d. r is computed and rounded to the nearest representable value using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode.

So here, `519 / 101.6` is a little over 5 (it's between 5 and 6).  Thus, the integer "q" in this case is `5`, and `101.6 * 5` is `508` (almost).  The result of the subtraction is `11.000000000000028`.

Comment: So if we swap this to be 508 / 101.6 = 5. Why exactly does 508 % 101.6 come out as a 0.00... value? And if that is by design is there a reasonable way to handle this?

Comment: @Nunners well the remainder after dividing 508 by 101.6 is (almost) zero.  The paragraph I quoted is from the spec, so yes it's by design. What you get from the `%` with floating-point numbers is the remainder after an *integer* division.